# Get xml data from database to mvc application

Tags: c#, xml, database, model-view-controller

I have a variable named "value" that are connected to a remote database and has the value of a xml string. Im wondering how I can take the values from that xml string and display them in my mvc index.cshtml. Do you need to do a model class that repressents the values in the xml string? I need help knowing what to search for, any help will do alot
thx in advance and I hope you understand my concern.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a little vague but I will try my best to answer it. You can use this to load an XElement from and XML file and then convert that to JSON and then convert to an object.

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(path);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, omitRootObject: true);
Console.WriteLine(json);
File.Delete(path);
var wbexport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WbExport<Column>>(json);
```

If you are trying to load a string value from a field in a database then you should look at an ORM solution like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) or [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)

Dapper:

```
using(var sql = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")))
{
    await sql.OpenAsync();
    var val = await sql.QueryAsync("<query to get your xml value>");
}
```